# Uson jsTree with custom JSON structure

Tags: json, formatting, jstree

I've been searching for ways to do this, but I'm missing something.

I have a custom JSON object, which can basically have **any** structure, and I want to use this with jsTree. I've found a corresponding plugin [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data), that claims to have a `_parse_json` function to transform a custom JSON object to the format that jsTree requires, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to call that plugin. It seems to be included in the version of jsTree that I'm using (1.0rc3).

There is a usage of UIMTreeProcessor I've found, that consists of parsing the XML and calling jsTree like so:

```
$.jstree._themes = "Content/jstreethemes/";

this.treeEl.jstree({
    "json_data" : {
        "data":data,
        "progressive_render":"true"
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "ui", "json_data" ],
    "core": { "animation": 0 }
    });
```

Now, instead of UIMTreeProcessor parsing the XML and populating `data`, I want to call `$.json_data._parse_json()`, but I keep getting errors that this function doesn't exist.

Can anyone show me an example? Thank you kindly.

Comment: I was trying my luck with this issue too, but it seems to me that this plugin requires the json in the format the documentation describes :/

Comment: Yes, it does, I was hoping that the json_data plugin can do this for me automatically.